# Using node in local network as provider

Tags: web3js, nodes, network, connections

I am using web3js, I've set up an ethereum node in my network in a laptop via mist, now I'd like to run a web3js script that uses that node as provider;

```
var PROVIDER = "192.168.1.40:8545" // I've also tried 30303
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(PROVIDER))
web3.eth.getBalance(TARGET_WALLET_ADDRESS);
```

This throws error

> CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node 192.168.1.40:8545.

Port 30303 shows as open, while 8545 shows as filtered. Is there any configuration step I'm missing? I'm supposed to use port 8545 right?

Also, I have a question:

- Can I use the node if it's not fully synced? By use I mean get balance of an account and do transactions

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should allways use localhost or 127.0.0.1 when conecting to local nodes.

You should be able to use a node while syncing, but the result will be outdated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate why I should connect to localhost? it should be almost the same right?

Comment: No, localhost/127.0.0.1 doesn't exit the machine, so it won't matter which ports are open to the outside